# PHP | String to Int conversion goes wrong

Tags: php

Hello my dear coding friends.
I have a time, formatted like this 08:00:00. That time comes from my phpMyAdmin database where i have a "time" field and i get that field by using a query in my php code. The variable type of that mysqli variable containing the time is string, so i want to cut the minutes and seconds part off and turn the rest into an integer by adding (int). The code looks like this: [Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5N8v.png)

```
if (strpos ($meetings["dtStartZeit"], "0") == 0) {
                            
    $startTimeString = substr ($meetings["dtStartZeit"], 1, 1);
                            
} else {
                        
    $startTimeString = substr ($meetings["dtStartZeit"], 0, 2);
                            
}
                        
$startTimeNumber = (int)$startTimeString;
```

Now comes the confusing part. If i have a string like this --> "8" and I want to turn it into an integer by using the above mentioned function, the result is 9 and not 8. The even more confusing part is that if I increase the value of that variable by 1, the result is 8.

Can someone explain me this please?

Comment: Please put the code as text :)

Comment: don't use `strpos(...) == 0` because this matches both 0 (meaning it's at the very start of the string) and false (meaning it does not exist in the string), that's almost always a bug, and in the rare case where it's actually intended, you should add that as a comment in the style of ```// this is NOT a bug! really need to check if it starts-with-or-doesnt-exist``` - instead use `=== 0` or `=== false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `strpos` or `substr` here. Use a single line type cast instead all of your code:

```
$startTimeNumber = (int) $meetings['dtStartZeit']; // "08:00:00" --> 8
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert a string to an int you use [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

because a string is an object of chars casting them wont ever work as expected which is what `(int)` is doing

Comment: "casting them wont ever work", this is wrong, you can most definitely cast a `string` to an `int`, this is taken from the [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):  "If the string is [numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php) or leading numeric then it will resolve to the corresponding integer value, otherwise it is converted to zero (`0`)." In the example `echo (int) "27test";`, the value 27 is returned, confirming casting does indeed work.

Comment: Did you both just miss the great big red flaming box above that message? "Never cast an unknown fraction to int, as this can sometimes lead to unexpected results." time information in a format is region based some regions don't use a `:` to format, also on the numeric page your linked @RJK it shows exactly why you should not use cast `"0E1" == "000"` are the same because of bad practise correction, by won't ever work I mean won't every work 100% as expected with all inputs which is what you need when building systems.